# How to add js to button submit in form popup?

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

I want applicate **Ajax** to submit button in *pop-up form.*

Thanks for help

Comment: Show us your trials

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I add class to <button  class.. > et dans mon js : $.('.class')..... Clic function but that doesn't work

Comment: the question is too vague, how do you make the popup?

Comment: I have contact form display in popup, I need applicate JS to my submit form.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to attach my popup

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-contact', function(e) {
      console.log("hello");
    });
```